# Jquery UI Sortable Grid Pinned Items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grid, jquery-ui-sortable, sticky

I've been spending all day trying to figure out how to make a jquery ui sortable grid, with pinned / sticky / locked items.

Searching around on stack and google has gotten me this far:

```
 $(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        start: function () {
            $(this).find(".pinned").each(function () {
                $(this).data("fixedIndex", $(this).index());
            });
        },        
        change: function () {
            $(this).find(".pinned").each(function () {
                $(this).detach().insertAfter($("#sortable li:eq(" + ($(this).data("fixedIndex")-1) + ")"));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mvirik/9ear1n3o/17/

This seems to work fine, but if I add "pinned" class to first or last item, it all breaks down.

Any help would be really great. Thank you!

Comment: By *"pinned"* you mean an item that can't be dragged..?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
 $(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        start: function () {
            $(this).find(".pinned").each(function () {
          $(this).data("fixedIndex", $(this).index());
            });
        },        
        change: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).find(".pinned").each(function () {
        if($(this).data("fixedIndex") != 0) {
            $(this).detach().insertAfter($("#sortable li:eq(" + ($(this).data("fixedIndex")-1) + ")"));
        } else {
            $(this).detach().insertBefore($("#sortable li:eq(" + ($(this).data("fixedIndex")) + ")"));
        }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Attempt 54: https://jsfiddle.net/mvirik/9ear1n3o/54/ :)

If anyone know a better way to do it, feel free to comment.

Edit: All though, I also want to be able to move the red items. This is still not working correctly.